# what is the meaning of a = [ ], i, j,len; in javascript where 'a' is any variable?

Tags: javascript

I have been reading a code written in java script where variables are assigned such values and I am unable to make out what exactly it is. Can anyone please specify ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var a = [], i, j, len;
```

defines four variables, `a`, `i`, `j`, and `len`, and gives `a` an initial value of an empty array.

Comment: Thank you so much. Given some block- solve:function(l1,l2){...}. Is 'solve' the name of a function?

Comment: @user3365120 In a way - it's really a name pointing to a function.

Comment: When is $ passed as the parameter of a function in jquery?

Comment: @user3365120: Usually in a function passed to `jQuery` or `jQuery(document).ready`, or in an IIFE. It makes sure that `$` is bound to `jQuery` within the function without changing the global definition of `$`. This allows the use of `$` in plugins and such while remaining friendly with [`noConflict`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict).

Answer (score 0):

It's not "any variable", it's an array.  You can change that later b/c javascript is not strongly typed.  The list of things separated by commas just defines them as existing.